# Build android application using HTML

Tags: android, html

I'm an Android newbie and I would like to learn how to build Android applications using HTML. What is the best way to start? Please suggest some good links and e-books.

Also, I would like to study from basic to advance topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Appcelerator!!!  It's multi-platform and the documentation is better than the competition.

http://www.appcelerator.com/platform

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your reply. I have looked in the site and am downloading now.

Answer (score 1):

Use phone gap for that.

here is a link to start with it

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start

Comment: Thank you for the link... will surely look into it and will come back if struck some where.

Comment: hey thats the basic idea on how to start with phonegap...if u like the answer please accept my answer

Comment: u can see a tick mark on the left hand side of the question mark that

Answer (score 1):

use [PhoneGap Library](http://phonegap.com) to make android app in `HTML` , it is basically javascript

no need use native android sdk

and for Mobile UI you can use [JQUERY MOBILE](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the link... will surely look into it and will come back if struck some where.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap, cooconjs, and the newest is crosswalk. The easiest is phonegap using [adobe phonegap builder](https://build.phonegap.com/). You also can see consturct 2 website in community forum to learn about converting html to apk using those services.

In my experience phonegap build is the easiest service to use, use just upload the html files and config file to [Adobe Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) in zip file. But, when I use it in my android 2.3.4, some animation (css animation) not work properly, but using another phone (android 4+), it looks very good as I expected.

It need to be noticed that phonegap is a library that can be use in your eclipse. Meanwhile Phonegap Build is a service from Adobe that allow us to make an apk/ios file easily.

Another service cocoonjs, the apk file is good in any android device (as long as I tried), and they say they add graphic accelerator to the app. The weakness of the service is the apk file is so big.

The last is Crosswalk. I've never use this application yet, but as far as I know this is also a good application.

Hope it helps...